# Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-winrt

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.7.1 on Windows 10 Home Version 10.0.16299 32-bit, Windows SDK Version 10.0.17134.12 and C++/WinRT Version 1.0.180505.2. When I try to create a new project using any of C++/WinRT templates, I'm getting this error message:

`Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards, Version=15.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more 
information on this problem and how to enable this template, 
please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.`

Is there an easy fix to this problem?

Answer (score 8):

This error was caused by missing UWP SDK. My first installation of Visual Studio was configured for `Desktop development with C++` workfload only, so `UWP development` workload components were missing. I added `UWP development` workload using Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: which UWP SDK was missing? add some details if others also ru into this issue.

Comment: The "Universal Windows Platform" workload includes a number of tools including the wizard that prompts for which version of the Windows SDK to use. My own [Direct3D VS Game Template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki#windows-10-sdk-usage) require the UWP workload even for Win32 desktop templates for that reason. With VS 2015 the same issue happened if you didn't have the "Windows Tools" optional component installed.

Comment: For VS 2017 C++ UWP development, you need the "UWP workload" (``Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal``) as well as the optional feature "C++ Universal Windows Platform tools" (``Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.VC``)

Comment: Thanks Paul, this was reported on the [C++/WinRT VSIX Q&A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264#qna) as well and will be fixed in a future update.

Comment: Does that mean I need both? UWP + Desktop development?

Answer (score 3):

This error comes due to absence of UWP tools. For Visual Studio 2019, you simply have to go to **Extensions>Manage Extensions>Online and search for "UWP Essentials"** then download it for free. Close all Visual Studio windows and then when you open it again, the problem should be solved.

Comment: I also had to install "UWP development"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to install the whole UWP Essentials package.  It contains a lot, but it gives you everything to fix the issue.  Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates > Online and search for "UWP Essentials", and use the Visual Studio Installer to get it.

Comment: Works, but took forever to download and install. Bit too much bloat